# How can I align lines between columns in a text?

Tags: vertical-alignment, two-column

[image: Align lines between two columns.]

Procurei de várias maneiras reproduzir no latex o texto mostrado na figura. Trata-se de um texto organizado em duas colunas onde existem linhas que estão alinhadas entre estas duas colunas.

Comment: See package [`pdfcolparcolumns`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcolparcolumns?lang=en), which is an improved version of `parcolumns`. But there are other choices on CTAN under the topic [parallel](https://www.ctan.org/topic/parallel). The most advanced package is probably [`reledpar`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledpar), but that may be overkill for your needs.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In general it is better to post compilable code, as a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), as this makes it easier for people to help you - and hence more likely that they will.

Comment: Problem solved! I used paracol package.